# using sqlite3 and php 5.2 to make a database (using apache 2.2 on windows)

Tags: database, sqlite, php-5.2, apache2.2

I'm trying to create a database where I'm to store data from a form into an sqlite database. I can't seem to be able to link the two, I keep getting errors. Here's my code for the query in the php file:

```
<?php
 $dbhandle = new SQLiteDatabase('sqlitedb');
 $result = $dbhandle->arrayQuery('SELECT name, email FROM users LIMIT 25', SQLITE_ASSOC);
 foreach ($result as $entry) {
     echo 'Name: ' . $entry['name'] . '  E-mail: ' . $entry['email'];
 }
?>
```

And this is the error message that shows:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_open() in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\vhosts\scotiaguestpro\extract.php on line 2

I manually created a database and tables with data in command prompt to query through. The database file is in the same directory as the php file.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.2.x does not support sqlite3, only sqlite2.
If you really need sqlite3 support, update to PHP 5.3.x.
Probably the best option anyway since PHP 5.2.x is not supported anymore by the PHP crew.